# How to prevent west and East elements from overlapping center in BorderLayout

Tags: layout, codenameone

I'm trying to create a layout in this sketch

[image: sketch]

I want to have a vertical slider in the center, one SpanLabel on the left and another on the right.

I've tried using BorderLayout, but the SpanLabels overlap the slider if their texts are long. Is there a Layout that I could use to achieve a similar style or something I could do to fix BorderLayout?

CenterAbsolute and CenterCenter don't help in fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `TableLayout` with percentages for each column to achieve this sort of layout.

`BorderLayout` assumes the preferred size of the elements on the sides/top/bottom isn't too big to cover everything so it's a bit problematic in some use cases.

Comment: I've thought about this, I'm just afraid of the percentage allocated to the bar being too small or too big on some devices. But since it's the only potential solution, I will go for it. I will use 10% for the bar, that should be enough.

Comment: There are other alternatives such as more elaborate layout managers like gridbaglayout, mig or even a custom layout manager.

Comment: Any example usage of GridBagLayout? I have never used this before.

Comment: Didn't use it much either. You can use the NetBeans gui builder with awt to do the layout in Java SE and just copy the code

Comment: TableLayout seems to do the job right, but the problem I'm having now is the SpanLabel unnecessarily breaking to next line. Is there a way to reflow SpanLabel now?

Comment: Does it happen if you call `TextArea.setUseStringWidth(true)`?

Comment: It's fixed thanks, I mistakenly swapped rows for columns in my TableLayout.